# SQL удалить все частичные дублирования определений

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица для справочника

### Таблица БД - words

```
word    | description 
--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
кот     | Самец кошки
кот     | Самец кошки семейства кошачьих отряда хищных
кот     | Домашнее животное является одним из подвидов дикой кошки 
бегемот | Крупное парнокопытное млекопитающее
бегемот | Крупное парнокопытное млекопитающее с массивным туловищем и короткими ногами
```

Нужно для каждого термина из справичника удалить все частичные дублирования определений, оставив только самые полные неповторяющиеся

### Ожидаемый результат после выполнения запроса

```
word    | description 
--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
кот     | Самец кошки семейства кошачьих отряда хищных
кот     | Домашнее животное является одним из подвидов дикой кошки 
бегемот | Крупное парнокопытное млекопитающее с массивным туловищем и короткими ногами
```

### P.S. - просьба учесть

1) определения могут быть также и длинными, тысяча знаков и даже более

2) количество записей в таблице — несколько сотен тысяч

Пробую так:

```
select word, distinct(description) from words
```

Что я делаю не так и как написать правильный запрос?

Comment: да, пока берем без отличий по буквам

Comment: В таблице есть какой нибудь уникальный ключ ? Потому что сейчас что бы не выбрать записи из за того что они равны сами себе надо сравнивать description на неравенство. Но в этом случае не будут найдены полные дубли. А если как то и придумать как выбрать еще и полные дубли удалить их будет крайне затруднительно

Comment: @Mike Ключей нет и добавлять не будем, только два столбца word и description

Comment: Ладно. А могут ли быть все таки ситуации полного совпадения слова и описания. т.е. если запись "кот=Самец кошки" встретится более одного раза ?

Comment: И кстати все таки, надо получить более длинные названия или выполнить именно delete, который удалит лишние записи

Comment: И если удалить - то полные дубли, если они есть из таблицы где нет первичного ключа удалить невозможно ибо при удалении будет невозможно отличить одну запись от другой

Comment: @Mike давайте без delete, просто делаем нужную выборку с нужным результатом, ситуации полного совпадения слова и описания теоретически возможны, т.k. данные беруться из разных источников, но по факту пока таких нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct A.*
  from words A
  left join words B
    on B.description like concat('%',A.description,'%')
   and A.word=B.word
   and A.description!=B.description
 where B.word is null
```

`distinct` нужен на случай если в таблице присутствуют полные дубли. Но он может замедлять работу запроса, если дублей заведомо нет - то его можно убрать. Так же очень приветствуется наличие в таблице первичного ключа, тогда в условии соединения таблиц можно проверять на неравенство этого первичного ключа, что надежнее проверки на неравенство description и помогло бы найти полные дубли.

Кроме того в этом запросе проверяется вхождение строки даже в середину другой строки, а не только в начало. Если нужно проверять только начало строки - убрать из `concat()` первый `%`

`left join` пытается найти для каждой записи A такие записи B где было бы вхождение подстроки (`like '%строка%'`). Т.е. он найдет записи для которых существует более длинное описание. Условие `where B.word is null` оставляет в выборке только те записи, для которых `left join` ничего не нашел.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо большое! Если Вам не будет сложно, дополните пожалуйста запрос комментариями, хочу разобраться и понять как это работает

Comment: @holdmeseven Написал. надеюсь, понятно сформулировал

Comment: $Mike постараюсь завтра разобраться с каждой строчкой, с Вашего позволения, если у меня возникнут вопросы я напишу. Еще раз Спасибо!

Comment: @holdmeseven Да, именно с каждой строчкой, запроса. поэспериментируйте (на кошках :) ), сделайте просто `*` а не только `A.*`, уберите `where` посмотрите что получилось

Comment: $Mike Все приму к сведению! Буду тренироваться на кошках!))

Answer (score 0):

Запрос

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t2.description LIKE CONCAT(t1.description, '%')
```

даст все КОРОТКИЕ описания. Остаётся их удалить...